# After deploying rails app to Heroku, no dropdowns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

After deploying my rails app to heroku, there are no dropdown menus!

When running locally, my source looks like this :

```
        <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.button.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.slider.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.base.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.all.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/foundation_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/admins.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/associates.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/dasharea.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/database.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/members.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/assets/vendor/custom.modernizr.js?body=1"></script>
        <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="anbyACcBlOI2Zpa9E2TImosNiBYN5KFTC8heYI1TE+I=" name="csrf-token" />

        <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
        <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.position.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.button.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.mouse.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.draggable.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.droppable.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-bounce.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-clip.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-drop.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fade.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fold.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-highlight.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-pulsate.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-scale.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-shake.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-slide.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-transfer.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.slider.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.sortable.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.all.js?body=1"></script>
        <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
```

In Heroku, it look like this :

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.ui.all.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js"></script>
```

But the links in Heroku return not found!

For a special reason, I included the jquery in my head manually like this :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery_ujs' %>
```

Is this the reason things are failing? How to fix it without removing these from the head?

Comment: Do you see `application.js` and `application.css` in heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (most) production setups, only the files in `public/assets` are available for use directly in `link` or `script` tags.

When you push to Heroku, it precompiles `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` by merging and compressing all javascript files required in `application.js` into a single file at `public/assets/application-xxxxxx.js`. Individual files, such as `jquery.js`, are not available. Therefore, it's recommended to use

```
<!-- HTML -->
javascript_include_tag 'application'

// inside app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

However, if you insist on including jquery manually without requiring it in `application.js`, you can add it to `config.assets.precompile`.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ['jquery.js', 'jquery_ujs.js']
```

(**Note**: A friend told me that Heroku doesn't read `production.rb` during precompilation. If that's the case, try adding the above to `config/application.rb` instead.)

When you push to Heroku and precompile your assets, you should see

```
$ rake assets:precompile
I, []  INFO -- : Writing public/assets/jquery-36fecc5eda81b43bdf4f92ce2d874df2.js
I, []  INFO -- : Writing public/assets/jquery_ujs-02181b3e64cd9e4e8548cad033516231.js
```

On Heroku, the script tags should now look like

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-36fecc5eda81b43bdf4f92ce2d874df2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect. I removed the javascript include tags and added `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` to the head. I simply wanted to load the javascript in the header instead of the footer. But now, my application have two application.js files both in the header where I added it and on the footer where it normally loads! How to remove the footer code?

Comment: It's probably in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.